# Xubuntu 14.10 (Thunar) won't auto-mount exfat partitions even with exfat-fuse and exfat-utils installed

Tags: mount, xubuntu, 14.10, automount, thunar

I have a flashdrive that is formatted with exfat where I store all my documents and such. I have successfully used it with ArchLinux and Nautilus, where it auto-mounted when plugged in without any issues once I installed the proper utilities.

With Xubuntu 14.10 64-bit, I am having a problem. With the utilities installed (fuse-exfat exfat-utils) I can manually mount the exfat drive as root, and this works fine. But when I plug it into the computer, Thunar simply refuses to auto-mount it or even show it in the sidebar. How can I get this to work? It's really annoying to have to manually mount it when I know there's a better way.

I have all updates installed, and no PPA's on the system. This is a completely fresh install, besides VLC and Google Chrome.

Comment: That's really weird.  I use XFCE on my daily driver, but all of my storage devices I use every day are ext4 or NTFS.  I'll try to find one that uses fat to see if I can replicate.

Comment: Please remember to format as EXfat not FAT or FAT32. FAT and FAT32 partitions automount fine, but EXFAT partitions don't. I use EXFAT because it supports read/write on all operating systems including OSX and doesn't have the 4GB filesize limit of FAT32.